# wget missing from cygwin install

Tags: cygwin, wget

I was trying to install oh-my-zsh and found an article requiring 'wget' to do that.

My install of cygwin64 on Windows 7 did not contain 'wget' -- I searched for it in the search filter of the setup program and wget was not one of the installable items. Any idea why that would be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mirror you're using is probably out of date or lacking packages for some reason.  Try specifying a different mirror, or multiple mirrors in the setup program.  The current list is at https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html.

Comment: So much for my mental model of what 'mirror' means. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to correctly point out that you looking for not installed package wget. It's available via cygwin distribution, as well as debug version and pwget, the perl version.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Cygwin with commandline options.
Its listed here `https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli`

Add commandline arguments such as `setup-x86_64.exe -p wget lynx`  is one way.
On the other hand, 
While you install, on the 'Select Packages' page, search wget, lynx, ssh or anyother package that you need. All good to go!